# User Controller not showing sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails application that I am trying to integrate devise_invitable into.  So, of course the authentication system is Devise.  Devise doesn't do the signups rather, it is handled by a CRUD controller so only an admin can use it to sign up.

In my code at the top I have:

```
class UsersController<ApplicationController
```

I'm not sure if it has to be changed to

```
class UsersController<Devise::InvitationsController
```

because, when I try to do it my route says that /users is not a path.

The CRUD controller is simple with new looking like this:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

I also don't think it is the view as I added a debug to to the log file when it gets into it,and it does.  Plus, this was working fine before I tried to add devise_invitable.

Any ideas on to why it would not display the form?  The console is also not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add an equals sign in front of form_for so instead of `<% form_for(user)%>` use `<%=form_for(user)%>`